# Postman shows 200 Ok but in response it is showing error for odoo api?

Tags: postman, odoo

I am hitting an odoo api, which gives 200 ok status but in response gives xml error response. I also attach the screenshot of postman [image: error]

I am just following the official documentation of odoo and want a response of server version. **Can you show me in post man that how can we get the server version response in postman.** https://www.odoo.com/documentation/13.0/webservices/odoo.html#logging-in

**Host url:**
'https://duduslimmer-odoo-huge-stage-545860.dev.odoo.com',

**Databse url:**
'duduslimmer-odoo-huge-stage-545860',

I want this kind of response:

```
{
    "server_version": "13.0",
    "server_version_info": [13, 0, 0, "final", 0],
    "server_serie": "13.0",
    "protocol_version": 1,
}
```

But getting this response:

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<methodResponse>
    <fault>
        <value>
            <struct>
                <member>
                    <name>faultCode</name>
                    <value>
                        <int>1</int>
                    </value>
                </member>
                <member>
                    <name>faultString</name>
                    <value>
                        <string>Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 69, in xmlrpc_2
    response = self._xmlrpc(service)
  File "/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/addons/base/controllers/rpc.py", line 48, in _xmlrpc
    params, method = loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 1019, in loads
    p.feed(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/xmlrpc/client.py", line 439, in feed
    self._parser.Parse(data, 0)
xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0
</string>
                    </value>
                </member>
            </struct>
        </value>
    </fault>
</methodResponse>
```

Can you please check is my POST URL correct means did i have to mention word 'version' in this url too.

The response i got when send json body of version:
**Json body:**

```
{
    "methodCall": {
        "methodName": "version",
        "params": "omi"
    }
}
```

**Json response:**

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": null,
    "error": {
        "code": 200,
        "message": "Odoo Server Error",
        "data": {
            "name": "werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest",
            "debug": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py\", line 656, in _handle_exception\n    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)\n  File \"/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py\", line 314, in _handle_exception\n    raise pycompat.reraise(type(exception), exception, sys.exc_info()[2])\n  File \"/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/tools/pycompat.py\", line 87, in reraise\n    raise value\n  File \"/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py\", line 698, in dispatch\n    result = self._call_function(**self.params)\n  File \"/home/odoo/src/odoo/odoo/http.py\", line 322, in _call_function\n    raise werkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest(msg % params)\nwerkzeug.exceptions.BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: <function RPC.xmlrpc_2 at 0x7f8a69ab3a60>, /xmlrpc/2/common: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'\n",
            "message": "400 Bad Request: <function RPC.xmlrpc_2 at 0x7f8a69ab3a60>, /xmlrpc/2/common: Function declared as capable of handling request of type 'http' but called with a request of type 'json'",
            "arguments": [],
            "exception_type": "internal_error"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What body did you post?

Comment: This is the body that i had posted

Comment: Whether i pass this body or not, i am still getting 200 OK

Comment: Can you share some screenshot of your postman that how you are passing the data

Answer (score 0):

Try using that body:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<methodCall>
<methodName>version</methodName>
<params/>
</methodCall>
```

If you want to do it manually, then https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC has a bit of info on how to create XML-RPC requests.

Then the endpoint is `/jsonrpc`
and body is probably something like that `{"service":"common","method": "version", "params": {}}`
But the JSON API is not well documented, I never used it directly.

Comment: I convert this xml body to json body: 
{
 "methodCall": {
  "methodName": "version",
  "params": "omi"
 }
}

Comment: I edit my question and added json request and response. Now it is returning Odoo Server Error

Comment: https://duduslimmer-odoo-huge-stage-545860.dev.odoo.com/xmlrpc/2/common